# how to rename file name and change file extension

Tags: batch-file

I have list of the file which their extension are different, I want to know how by using batchfile I can do below modification?

BPG_ANNUITY **.pkb**  --- should rename to ---->  **PACKAGE BODY** BPG_ANNUIT Y **.sql**
BPG_ANNUITY **.pks**  --- should rename to ---->  **PACKAGE** BPG_ANNUITY **.sql**

I tried to rename the files by below comment but it was not working.

```
ren *.pks "PACKAGE *.sql"
ren *.pkb "PACKAGE body *.sql"
```

I received below error:

> A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.

would you mind help me? I am using windows 7,64bit.

Comment: The `ren` command renames files.

Comment: I tried but I recevie below msg : A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found.

Comment: I don't know of a single programming language in existence that would allow you to rename files the way you tried to.

Comment: @SomethingDark: Hello! it is not big deal in c#, but I would like to handle it is very simple manner by using batch file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use wildcards to rename files like that. You can, however, process a list of files and rename them one by one.

```
for /f %%A in ('dir /b *.pks') do ren %%A "PACKAGE %%~nA.sql"
for /f %%A in ('dir /b *.pkb') do ren %%A "PACKAGE BODY %%~nA.sql"
```

The first command will get a list of the names of all .pks files in the present directory (the `/b` option returns only the file name). The `~n` portion of %%~nA will return the file name without the extension - in your example, BPG_ANNUITY with no extension. The `ren` command then takes the old file name and changes it to `PACKAGE BPG_ANNUITY.sql` and continues with the rest of the .pks files in the directory.

The second command works the same way, but with .pkb files.

Comment: Thanks, it is working fine for most of the file but for few file I have problem for example "BPG_GREG_HIJ_DATE.pkb" "BPG_GREG_HIJ_DATE.pks" became  "PACKAGE _HIJ_DATE.sql"   "PACKAGE body DATE.sql"or  "BPG_CUS01.pks" became "PACKAGE 1.sql"

Comment: Any idea about the above comment?

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate your problem. I ran the code on those three file names and got `PACKAGE BODY BPG_GREG_HIJ_DATE.sql`, `PACKAGE BPG_GREG_HIJ_DATE.sql`, and `PACKAGE BPG_CUS01.sql`. It sounds like you have a space in your file names.

Comment: Should be `for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b *.pks') do ren "%%A" "PACKAGE %%~nA.sql"` etc. to treat all valid file names.

Comment: More like he should have mentioned that he had file names with spaces. I'm not a mind reader.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to conveniently rename your files via my [JREN.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) utility - a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
call jren "(.*\.)pks$" "PACKAGE $1sql"
call jren "(.*\.)pkb$" "PACKAGE BODY $1sql"
```